# Laravel - Can't chain my queries after running my haversine query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

I am filtering API results based on a users input, for example:

The user can say Show me offers which have a price between 10 and 50, I have got a query in to check the distance between the users lat/long and the lat/long in the offers table, when I post the parameters it all functions nicely and works.

However, if I post the lat long parameters and pass another set of parameters, the query breaks. For example:

```
//Working response
{
"offers": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "offer_name": "nah",
  "offer_description": "nah",
  "offer_price": 100,
  "offer_repeat": null,
  "offer_photo": null,
  "offer_lat": "52.754646",
  "offer_long": "-1.251366",
  "offer_date_posted": null,
  "offer_start_date": null,
  "offer_end_date": null,
  "offer_date_repeat": null,
  "student_only": null,
  "offer_amount": "1",
  "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
  "created_at": null,
  "offer_cat_id": 1,
  "offer_price_type": null,
  "offer_venue_id": 1,
  "offer_location_id": 1,
  "distance": 104.01333767313
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "offer_name": "nope",
  "offer_description": "nope",
  "offer_price": 50,
  "offer_repeat": null,
  "offer_photo": null,
  "offer_lat": "51.754646",
  "offer_long": "-1.251366",
  "offer_date_posted": null,
  "offer_start_date": null,
  "offer_end_date": null,
  "offer_date_repeat": null,
  "student_only": null,
  "offer_amount": "1",
  "updated_at": null,
  "created_at": null,
  "offer_cat_id": 2,
  "offer_price_type": null,
  "offer_venue_id": 1,
  "offer_location_id": 1,
  "distance": 61.474296680605
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "offer_name": "nahn ha",
  "offer_description": "nah",
  "offer_price": 25,
  "offer_repeat": null,
  "offer_photo": null,
  "offer_lat": "51.754646",
  "offer_long": "-1.251366",
  "offer_date_posted": null,
  "offer_start_date": null,
  "offer_end_date": null,
  "offer_date_repeat": null,
  "student_only": null,
  "offer_amount": "1",
  "updated_at": null,
  "created_at": null,
  "offer_cat_id": 3,
  "offer_price_type": null,
  "offer_venue_id": 2,
  "offer_location_id": 2,
  "distance": 61.474296680605
}
]
}
```

//Query with the ID < 5 and have the same distance arguments as above

```
{
   "error": {
   "message": "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: select * from                (select *, (69.000000 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(51.507200)) *       COS(RADIANS(offer_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(0.127500 - offer_long)) +  SIN(RADIANS(51.507200)) * SIN(RADIANS(offer_lat))))) AS distance from `offers`  where `id` < 5 and offer_lat BETWEEN 47.159374 AND 55.855026 and offer_long  BETWEEN -6.857899 AND 7.112899) as d where `id` < 10 and `distance` between 300  and ?)",
    "code": "HY093",
    "status_code": 500
  }
  }
```

I think it has something to do with the fact I overwrite the $query variable in my model and still return it? I can show examples of my model file if needed, thanks for the help.

The query to run if user has set the following params: (this breaks if you try and set another filter with this one)

```
        if (isset($params['lat']) && trim($params['lat']) !== '' && isset($params['long']) && trim($params['long']) !=='' && isset($params['maxdist']) && trim($params['maxdist']) !=='' && isset($params['mindist']) && trim($params['mindist']) !=='')
    {
        $lat = $params['lat'];
        $lng = $params['long'];
        $radius = $params['maxdist'];
        $minRaidus = $params['mindist'];
        $lat = $lat + 0;
        $lng = $lng + 0;

        $units = 'M';

        $distanceUnit = $this->distanceUnit($units);

        if (!(is_numeric($lat) && $lat >= -90 && $lat <= 90)) {
            echo 'fix2';
            var_dump($lat);
        }

        if (!(is_numeric($lng) && $lng >= -180 && $lng <= 180)) {
            echo 'fix1';
        }

        $haversine = sprintf('*, (%f * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(%f)) * COS(RADIANS(offer_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(%f - offer_long)) + SIN(RADIANS(%f)) * SIN(RADIANS(offer_lat))))) AS distance',
            $distanceUnit,
            $lat,
            $lng,
            $lat
        );

        $subselect = clone $query;
        $subselect
            ->selectRaw(DB::raw($haversine));


        $latDistance      = $radius / $distanceUnit;
        $latNorthBoundary = $lat - $latDistance;
        $latSouthBoundary = $lat + $latDistance;
        $subselect->whereRaw(sprintf("offer_lat BETWEEN %f AND %f", $latNorthBoundary, $latSouthBoundary));

        $lngDistance     = $radius / ($distanceUnit * cos(deg2rad($lat)));
        $lngEastBoundary = $lng - $lngDistance;
        $lngWestBoundary = $lng + $lngDistance;
        $subselect->whereRaw(sprintf("offer_long BETWEEN %f AND %f", $lngEastBoundary, $lngWestBoundary));

     $query
            ->from(DB::raw('(' . $subselect->toSql() . ') as d'))
            ->whereBetween('distance', [$minRaidus, $radius]);
    }
```

For testing sake, i am just saying where the ID is less than the users id parameter, this is so i can fix the distance query breaking when chaining

```
    if (isset($params['id']) && trim($params['id']) !== '' )
    {
        $query->where('id', '<', trim($params['id']));
    }
```

And where I call my queryscope:

```
    if ($request){
        $params = $request->all();
        $offers = Offer::filter($params)->SortByFilter($params)->get();
        return $offers;
    }
```

Comment: post your code in question

Comment: Done @ChetanAmeta :)